# How to print an element in the controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an element in my controller, which has no form name. How can I print/echo that element in my view back to the user?

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_button('name');
$name->setAttrib('id', 'bouton');
$name->setLabel('name');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Controller assign it to the view:

```
$this->view->name = $name;
```

in View echo it:

```
<?php echo $this->name; ?>
```